# Matlab function to replace coordinates in a matrix with alternate value

Tags: matlab, double

I have a cell in MATLAB. For the sake of simplicity

```
a{1,1} = zeros(150,5)
```

I also have a 50x2 double that contains the coordinates that I want to replace with another value, an oddball value

```
OddballRow = transpose(sort(randperm(150,50)+1)); %provides random rows
OddballColumn = randi(5, [50,1])+1; %provides random columns
Oddball = [OddballRow OddballColumn]; %matrix with row and column wanted next to each other
```

I want to take the coordinate defined above (Oddball, [row column]) and replace those values in the matrix with something else, for simplicity the word 'oddball'.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: When I try ```Task_Test{1,1}(sub2ind([150 5], OddballRow, OddballColumn))= 'oddball'; 
``` I get the error code "Conversion to cell from double is not possible."

Comment: I think where one of my main issues is arising is that the cell isn't converting to a matrix

Comment: When you do `Task_Test{1,1}(…)='oddball'` you are trying to stick a char array into a double array. This has nothing to do with cell arrays, other than that your double array is stored inside one. Please clarify what you intend to do.

Comment: Matlab defines A{1,1} as a cell however it contains all of my data within it. Since yesterday I was able to convert it into a 151x24 cell however it is still not a double like I am used to working with which is why I except some of what I have been trying isn't working as usual. All I want to do is replace the coordinates in Oddball that can be found in A{1,1} with the word 'oddball'